# Ability to flip div boxes, changing their size, and interacting with the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a design with small clickable div boxes, that once clicked they flip by 180° and show content. Content which you can interact with: like clicking links, copy text or change the content with the use of more buttons.

I've managed to accomplish this, but my question follows: Is there a better way for this?

Found this website of a basic [example](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/)

But being CSS based the content on the other side isn't interactable.

This is the code:

### *HTML*

```
<div id="saos">
    <div id="pg1" style="display:none;">
        <blockquote>Page1</blockquote><br>
        Yay content.
    </div>
    <div id="pg2" style="display:none;">
        <blockquote>Page2</blockquote><br>
        More content.
    </div>
    <div class="x" style="display:none;" onclick="closePage()">
        <p>X</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="an2 start startbak" onclick="openPage()">
        <p class="sp">Click!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cont" style="display:none;">
        <p class="sp">Click!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### *CSS*

```
.write {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0055ff;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s cubic-bezier(.08, 1, .08, 1);
    left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.write:hover {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px)scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px)scale(1.2);
}
.write p {
    color: #002164;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.an {
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s cubic-bezier(.08, 1, .08, 1);
}
.an2 {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
}
.page {
    background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, .8);
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    border: 2px solid #252525;
    height: 330px;
    width: 530px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #818181;
}
.start {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 290px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px)rotateY(180deg)translateZ(-10px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px)rotateY(180deg);
}
.start:hover {
    background-color: #0055ff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.startbak {
    background-color: #0036a3;
}
.mainbak {
    background: #252525;
}
.sp {
    color: #002164;
    margin-top: 43px;
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg)rotateZ(-45deg)translateZ(-10px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg)rotateZ(-45deg);
}
.frame {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 751px;
    height: 452px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px)rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px)rotateY(0deg);
}
.x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 700px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #c75050;
    color: #fff;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 2;
}
.x:hover {
    background-color: #e04343;
    cursor: default;
}
.x:active {
    background-color: #993d3d;
}
.x p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### *JavaScript*

```
var htmlString = '<div class="f an write" style="top: 10px;" name="Home" onClick="openTab(\'pg1\',\'0\')"><p>Home</p></div>\n'
htmlString += '<div class="f an write" style="top: 65px;" name="About" onClick="openTab(\'pg2\',\'1\')"><p>About</p></div>\n'

function openTab(id, n){
    for (var i=0;i<write.length;i++){
        write[i].className = 'f an write';    
        write[i].style.top = i*55+10+'px';
        name = write[i].getAttribute('name');
        write[i].innerHTML = '<p>'+name+'</p>';
    }
    write[n].className = 'f an page';
    write[n].style.top = '10px';
    write[n].innerHTML= '<div class="ins">'+document.getElementById(id).innerHTML+'</div>';
}

var id2 = document.getElementById('2'),
    x = document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0];

function openPage(){
    id2.className = 'an2 frame mainbak';
    setTimeout(function() {
        id2.className = 'an2 frame mainbak'
        id2.setAttribute('onclick','')
        document.getElementById('2').innerHTML=htmlString
    }, 150);
    setTimeout(function() {
        x.style.display='';
    }, 600);
}
function closePage(){
    id2.className = 'an2 start mainbak';
    setTimeout(function() {
        id2.className = 'an2 start startbak'
        id2.setAttribute('onclick','openPage()')
        document.getElementById('2').innerHTML=document.getElementById('cont2').innerHTML
    }, 150);
    x.style.display='none';
}
```

Also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzV9m/) but it doesn't seem to work..

While on my browser does.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this with only a couple of lines of Javascript. Rich Bradshaw's example that you posted was an excellent starting point.

Rather than starting the flip on hover (via css selectors) I added a couple of lines of Javascript - actually jQuery, but plain JS would work - to add the relevant class on click. It works really nicely...

**[See jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/tPWA3/2/)**

I also managed to get the back face clickable (as in that demo) so it should meet all of your needs.

By that method the HTML is reduced to:

```
<div id="f1_container">
    <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/281/" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
            <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
            <p>Any content can go here.</p>
            <p>Including interactive HTML like
                <a href="http://www.example.com/">links</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript is just:

```
$('#f1_container').click(function() {
    $('#f1_container').addClass('clicked');
});
```

Comment: This is what I sort of tried. But it became a mess on my side... Isn't it because while flipping the div box I was also trying to resize it at the same time?

Comment: Hi Marian, I couldn't help directly from your jsfiddle because it wasn't working. But please go into mine, update it with the sizing that you want, then save it and post back the updated link. If I can see a working example of the problem then we can hopefully fix it.